# What is the Storable module used for?

Tags: perl, module, perl-module, storable

I am having a hard time understanding what [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) does.

I know that it "stores" a variable into your disk, but why would I need to do that? What would I use this module for, and how would I do it?

Comment: it's not just for storing to disk - the stored data can be stored anywhere (memcache, database, sent over the network, whatever...)

Comment: for completeness I would have you look into [DBM::Deep](http://p3rl.org/DBM::Deep) too

Comment: The "how" part is using the module :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reasons that spring to mind:

- Persist memory across script calls
- Sharing variables across different processes (sometimes it isn't possible to pipe stuff)

Of course, that's not all that [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) does. It also:

- Makes it possible to create deep clones of data structures
- Serializes the data structure stored, which implies a smaller file footprint than output from [`Data::Dump`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDump)
- Is optimized for speed (so it's faster to `retrieve` than to `require` a file containing `Data::Dump` output

Comment: It's also potentially safer than `require`ing a [`Data::Dump`]() file because someone may have added some Perl code to the output of `Data::Dumper`. By default [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) doesn't `eval` any code it receives, so it is safer.

Answer (score 2):

One example:

Your program spends a long time populating your data structure, a graph, or trie, and if the program crashes then you'd lose it all and have to start again from square one. To avoid losing this data and be able to continue where it stopped last time you can save a snapshot of the data to a file manually or just simply use Storable.

Comment: Could I save STDIN? For example, if I wrote a program to take a name (in `$name`) and print "Hello, $name", could I use this to save all names ever used, and create a command to print the names?

Comment: @perl.j, It can be used to store an array, so yes, you could store a list of names.

Comment: @ikegami: How do I save input from the Perl "Diamond Operator"?

Comment: perl.j: it saves variables, not operators.  How you would capture anything ever read using `<>` into a variable is a completely different question, and not one related to storable at all.

Comment: @perl.j, Same as any other string.

Comment: @perl.j, `my $input = <>; store_fd(\$input, $fh);`

Comment: @ikegami: Will that store every `$input` on every use of the program?

Comment: @perl.j, What do you mean by "every $input"? There is only one `$input`.

Comment: @ikegami: I mean if I am going to frequently use this program, I will have several different `$input`'s, right? So how do I store every one of those `$input`'s?